# How to add Legend bar to Row Chart Dc.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I have a row chart that highlights each row based on the percentages, using colorAccessor() function:

```
    .colorAccessor(function(d) {
        var percentage = d.percentage;
        if(percentage >= 100) 
            return "green";
        else if(70 <= percentage && percentage < 100)
            return "yellow";
        else if (0 <= percentage && percentage < 70)
            return "red";
        return "blue";
    })
```

This is the color setting:

```
var color = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(["green","yellow", "blue", "red"])
                            .range(["#00FF00","#FFFF00","#3232ff", "#FF0000"]);
```

Now I want to add a legend bar to this row chart to highlight the domain of the colors. I've tried to include

```
.legend(dc.legend().y(475).itemHeight(13).gap(5))
```

but it doesn't work.

How should I do that?

Comment: sorry, it doesn't look like the row chart is "legendable" - added an issue.  https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/836

Answer (score 0):

This is related to this issue: https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/836 (Thanks Gordon!)

I created a temporary solution for the legend bars by HTML:

```
<div id='dc-legend'>
  <div id = "dc-legend-item">
    <div id = "dc-legend-item-color" style="background-color: #00FF00;">
    </div>
    <span id = "dc-legend-item-text"> Percentage >= 100% </span>
  </div>
      <div id = "dc-legend-item">
    <div id = "dc-legend-item-color" style="background-color: #FFFF00;">
    </div>
    <span id = "dc-legend-item-text"> 70% <= Percentage < 100% </span>
  </div>
      <div id = "dc-legend-item">
    <div id = "dc-legend-item-color" style="background-color: #FF0000;">
    </div>
    <span id = "dc-legend-item-text"> 0 <= Percentage < 70% </span>
  </div>
  <div id = "dc-legend-item">
    <div id = "dc-legend-item-color" style="background-color: #3232ff;">
    </div>
    <span id = "dc-legend-item-text"> No goals set </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The style would look like: (depending on what you wants)

```
#dc-legend-item-color{
    height: 20px; width: 20px;
    margin-top:2px;
    float:left;
    }

#dc-legend-item-text{
    margin-left: 20px;
    }

#dc-legend {
    width: 300px;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size:13px;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```